# Stopping serve Laravel on localhost after opening several pages

Tags: php, laravel-9

I am using Laravel version 9.52.6

After I run the `php artisan serve` command, the phrase `Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:8000]` is no longer visible.

But this is not the main problem. I can enter the above address in the browser and the site will open. But after opening a few pages, Laravel stops and requires me to execute the `php artisan serve` command twice.

**My service profile:**
Laravel version: 9.52.6
PHP Version: 8.2.4
Composer version: 2.5.5

The following error is displayed when stopping.

```
 ErrorException

  Undefined array key 1

  at D:\Edu\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:323
    319▕     protected function getRequestPortFromLine($line)
    320▕     {
    321▕         preg_match('/:(\d+)\s(?:(?:\w+$)|(?:\[.*))/', $line, $matches);
    322▕
  ➜ 323▕         return (int) $matches[1];
    324▕     }
    325▕
    326▕     /**
    327▕      * Get the console command options.

  1   D:\Edu\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:323
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}("U
ndefined array key 1", "D:\Edu\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeComma
nd.php")

  2   D:\Edu\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:253
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand::getRequestPortFromLine("9500 Accepted")
```

please help me

Comment: Is it possible that this problem is because my computer is weak?

Comment: Focus on one problem at a time.  "*Undefined array key 1*" is pretty clear, right?  It is telling you `$matches[1]` does not exist.  If you check [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), it tells you that can happen bcs the first subpattern did not match anything.  So you need to start debugging that first.  At the very least, your code should probably check that something matched before trying to return it, and handle the case when it did not.

Comment: This problem still exists. But instead of using PHP STORM's built-in terminal, I ran the codes with the help of xampp. The site works perfectly without errors. This indicates that there is a problem with PHPSTORM and its built-in emulator.